# Getting error of MySingleton in program. How to solve that error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on project where i am taking data from xampp server which is on my laptop and i am running app on physical device but in process i am getting error on MySingleton.
This is line where error occur. MySingleton is highlighted in red color.

```
MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

This is complete MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;
EditText phone;
Button search;
String number;
private ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("loading");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);



    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            number = phone.getText().toString().trim();

            getSqlDetails();
        }
    });


}

private void getSqlDetails() {

    String url= "http://192.168.43.12/data.php?phone="+number;
    pd.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    pd.hide();


                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                            String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
                            String price = jsonobject.getString("price");
                            String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                            String phone = jsonobject.getString("phone");

                            result.setText(" ID -"+id+"\n Price -"+price+"\n Name -"+name+"\n Phone -"+phone);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }

        }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
);
MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}


}
```

I had added internet permission in manifest too.
and volley dependence also

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Any solution on solving this problem is much appreciable.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: although i had added all required dependence than also android studio is highlighting  MySingleton in red color. how to solve it ????

Comment: close Android Studio and it won't be highlighted anymore... how can I tell you how to solve your problem, if you won't tell me what's your problem? Paste error or add screenshot...

Comment: sir i am new to android so i don't know lots of thing about it but i hope below error is what you are asking me.Error:(108, 57) error: cannot find symbol method addToRequestQueue(StringRequest)

Comment: seem like you haven't defined `addToRequestQueue(StringRequest sr)` method in your `MySingleton` class

Comment: how to define that ?

Comment: like any other method. perhaps, you're missing something from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#java) tutorial

Comment: sir do you have any idea that how can we break a line and start it from next line in toast. as /n or <br> does not work. hope you got what i want to say

Comment: it's `\n`, not `/n`

Comment: sorry for mistake i had use \n too but it does not work

Comment: Then you need to show me your attempt, because `\n` should work.